# How do I close an .OpenText().ReadLine() stream properly as I am getting "file in use by another process errors"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to read the string in the text file which contains the default image name and then close the ReadLine(). The way I am trying to close it now is no good and the process is not terminated and
causes "file being used by another process" errors elsewhere in the program, when the text file in question needs to be overwritten.

```
DirectoryInfo sourceDir = new DirectoryInfo(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("~/Content/ProductImages/" + Model.Products[i].ProductID.ToString() + "/thumbs/"));


               FileInfo[] defaultImage = sourceDir.GetFiles("defaultImage.txt");
               string defimg = defaultImage[0].OpenText().ReadLine();
               defaultImage[0].OpenText().Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You close the stream that you opened, instead of opening another stream and close that instead...

```
var stream = defaultImage[0].OpenText();
string defimg = stream.ReadLine();
stream.Close();
```

Or using a `using` block:

```
string defimg;
using (stream = defaultImage[0].OpenText()) {
  defimg = stream.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to read the first line:

```
using (var reader = defaultImage[0].OpenText())
{
    string defimg = reader.ReadLine();
}
```

or if you want to read the entire file contents into a string:

```
string defimg = File.ReadAllText(defaultImage[0].FullName);
```

Comment: @Guffa, sure, that's not much of a problem. You could use it inside.

Answer (score 0):

defaultImage[0].OpenText() Everytime creates a new StreamReader. So in your case, you are not closing the one which you have opened.
Below should work.

```
var sr = defaultImage[0].OpenText();
            string str = x.ReadLine();
            sr.Close();
```

Comment: using block is better and clean option.